# Can't open library window in interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am using a MacBook Pro installed with Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2. When I launch Interface Builder by clicking the nib file, then I do not see any library window. Anyone has idea on why it is behaving so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Xcode 4.1 view -> utilities -> show object library

Answer (score 4):

If you choose **Library** from the **Tools** menu, or if you press ⇧⌘L, does it not appear?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem just after updating to XCode 3.2.6 (IB is currently 3.2.6 also).
My machine is configured to work with two display screens but I don't always turn the smaller one on. 
I found the library to be present on the second screen.
How it got there I have no idea.
Try switching to a higher display resolution to see if a similar thing happened in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is there is no Interface Builder plugin for XCode 4. You probably cannot edit nib file in XCode 4.

Answer (score 0):

In the Xcode menu, choose View > Utilities > Size Inspector.

Make sure the Object library is visible in the pane below the Size inspector. If not, choose View > Utilities > Object Library.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my  interface builder screen doesn't show up, and I check my sytem resources and kill off some processes.  Apparently, 600 or 700 MB of memory left isn't enough for XB to launch

Answer (score 0):

it works using ⇧⌘L in xcode 3.2.6